# How can I fix "unable to convert dataset from 'JPEG Baseline' transfer syntax to 'Little Endian Explicit'" while using DCMTK-Toolkit?

Tags: dicom, dcmtk

I'm trying to send an image as a DICOM-file ((0002,0002) Media Storage SOP Class UID `1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.1.7` --> Secondary Capture Image Storage) with the DCMTK-Toolbox storescu to the ORTHANC testserver. Therefore I converted the image with the DCMTK-function "img2dcm" to a DICOM-file in Delphi. The Image seems to be converted correctly into a DICOM-file because "MicroDicom DICOM Viewer" shows the correct image with all relevant tags.
The error message I receive in the CMD is as following:

```
I: determining input files ...
I: checking input files ...
I: Requesting Association
I: Association Accepted (Max Send PDV: 16372)
I: Sending file: C:\Delphi5\Projects\Test_DICOM\Test_DICOM_IMG.dcm
I: Converting transfer syntax: JPEG Baseline -> Little Endian Explicit
I: Sending Store Request (MsgID 1, SC)
XMIT: W: DIMSE Warning: (MyAETitle,ORTHANC): sendMessage: unable to convert dataset from 'JPEG Baseline' transfer syntax to 'Little Endian Explicit'
E: Store Failed, file: C:\Delphi5\Projects\Test_DICOM\Test_DICOM_IMG.dcm:
E: 0006:020e DIMSE Failed to send message
E: Store SCU Failed: 0006:020e DIMSE Failed to send message
I: Aborting Association
```

It seems that storescu doesnt accept the (0002,0010)Transfer Syntax UID 1.2.840.10008.1.2.4.50 (JPEG Baseline(Process 1)) --> copied from MicroDicom DICOM Viewer.

I tried some network options for storescu in my Delphi-code like -xi or -xs:

```
Command := 'cd /d ' + dcmtkPath + '&&storescu -xs ' + IP + ' ' + Port + ' ' + DICOMPath +' +sd -ll info -aec ' +  AET +' -aet ' + edtAETitleMain.Text;
```

None of the options worked so far. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I just found my answer somewhere in the internet. I had to use "dcmdjpeg" from the DCMTK-Toolbox to decompress the image-DICOM-file i want to send with input the .dcm and output the same .dcm. This converted the Transfer Syntax JPEG Baseline to Little Endian Explicit.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding the flag `-xy` (or `--propose-jpeg8`) to the storescu command?

I see you used the `-xs` flag, but that is for lossless jpeg, and your file is lossy 8 bit jpeg (baseline 8 bit).

Comment: Yes I tried -xs, but it didn't work. I already found my solution and answered this question myself. Thanks for the input though! Appreciate it.

Comment: You should use -xy not -xs, then you don't need to convert the dicom file to another transfer syntax

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storescu, you could also use [dcmsend](https://blog.jriesmeier.com/2011/10/sending-dicom-files-more-easily/), which is also from the DCMTK, but easier to use. In particular, there is no need to set additional command line options for sending compressed DICOM images.